# MySql/MariaDB cannot change default datadir on Debian 9.1 server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian

I have a problem to move the default datadir of Maria DB to another partition, it appears to be very common but i tried everything I can without luck.

Mysql is installed as Mariadb 10.1.26 with the default debian package (`apt-get install mysql-server`) on a Debian 9.1 (stretch) server, `mysqld -v` returns `mysqld 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1`

Default_mysql_datadir : `/var/lib/mysql`

New_mysql_datadir : `/home/mysql`

`/var/lib/mysql` is mounted to "`/`" (`/dev/md3`)

`/home/mysql` is mounted to "`/home`" (`/dev/md4`)

What I've tried

```
# systemctl stop mysql
# mv /var/lib/mysql /home
```

Change datadir in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
datadir = /home/mysql
```

Check if the rights/permissions are ok

`# chown -R mysql.mysql /home/mysql`

**apparmor is NOT installed** nor running on the system though the `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` file is existing with the following rules :

```
/home/mysql/ r,
/home/mysql/** rwk,
```

I even tried to create and empty `/var/lib/mysq` folder refering to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1574782)

But when I start I always get the same error :

```
# systemctl start mysql
[Warning] Can't create test file /home/mysql/<user>.lower-test
#007/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/home/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied") 2017-09-07  0:16:59 140119808397888 [ERROR] Aborting
mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Failed to start MariaDB database server.
mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You must set **`ProtectHome=false`** in the systemd config file in order to move your datadir to the `/home` directory.

According to Debian policy rules, you should set this option value in a custom file like **`/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/YOUR_CUSTOM_FILE.conf`** containing:

```
[Service]

# Prevent accessing /home, /root and /run/user
ProtectHome=false
```

Then reload systemctl daemon:

`systemctl daemon-reload`

After that you should be able to change MariaDB datadir from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/home/mysql`.

Comment: We just ran into this after a version upgrade on a production server. We had to add ProtectSystem=false in addition to ProtectHome=false.

After adding ProtectHome=false, the error changed to: 
[ERROR] mysqld: File '/home/mysql/mysql-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 30 "Read-only file system")

When it was clearly not actually a read only situation.

Comment: [systemd documentation for mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/) contains this an other tips. Needing ProtectSystem=false seems odd. Did you miss running `daemon-reload` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This whitelist in `/etc/systemd/mariadb.service.d/whatever.conf`:

```
[Service]
ReadWritePaths=/home/mysql
```

may be another solution, but I would not have found it without [Mr. Payart's wisdom](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191174).

Comment: FYI:  It turns out the `ProtectHome=false` is also required.